# Adding FormCOntrol to formgroup is marking it as Valid after Angular urgrade

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

Recently we have upgraded to Angular13 but after that we are having issues related to form-group validation. When i am using below code to add new form-control to form-group then it is marking that as Valid even it has many control with no value and also required validator.

```
const selectedRegionControl = new FormControl(value);
(this.form.get('info') as FormGroup).addControl("selectedRegion", selectedRegionControl);
```

If i remove this code it works fine . Not sure how upgrading to Angular13 it is breaking it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's looks like work, see a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-osgygn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (rememeber that a FormControl or FormGroup can be valid, invalid, disabled or pending)

Comment: Thanks for it but in my case form is generated using formly and then i add control in that which is failing.

Comment: Then, I imagine you need, futhermore add the formControl, give new values to "fields" (sorry I've never use "formly")